# WebRTC one to many Screen Sharing

Tags: webrtc

For screen sharing, whenever we invoke `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` we need to **select the screen** that we wish to share, before the streaming can be started. This works fine if it is one to one sharing.

But if I am doing **1 to many** screen sharing, we have to create a separate WebRTC connection to each peer. The problem is, if I have 5 peers, I have to select the screen 5 times because every time I call  `getDisplayMedia()` for different peer, it will requires me to select the screen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call getDisplayMedia multiple times, you can add the track/stream from the first getDisplayMedia call to more than one peerconnection.

See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/ for a sample illustrating this. There is only a single call (to getUserMedia in this case)